# Make Twig syntax from string be parsed

Tags: symfony, twig

I stored a format of shopping order in database, it's like **#{{ number }}** (it's just a string), how can use this **{{ number }}** as a execution of Twig.

For example, in my Controller, when I render the view, I also pass a $number variable:

```
return $this->render('MyBundle:View:index.html.twig', array('number' => 123));
```

and in my index.html.twig file, it's something like

```
{% set orderFormat = some_function_to_get_order_format() %} 
// orderFormat will be #{{ number }}
// What can I do to print orderFormat to #123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [template_from_string](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html) function.

```
{{ include(template_from_string("Hello {{ name }}") }}
```

Comment: The function "template_from_string" does not exist.. What happened? I used Symfony 2.3

Comment: check that you have Twig 1.11 or more.

Comment: A little late, but you have also to enable StringLoader extension. Consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478219/activate-stringloader-twig-extension-in-symfony